# jcl error in ibm mainframe contest 2020 jcl1 problem

Tags: jcl

```
//setvar secret=(NEW,CATLG, DELETE)
```

This line giving me error unexpected left punctuation used.
What should I change ?

Answer (score 4):

Part of the point of the Master The Mainframe contest is for you to learn how to find these answers for yourself.  Having someone tell you the answer is probably...

> Your statement is syntactically invalid, at a guess it should be `//SETVAR SET SECRET=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE)`

...doesn't really teach you how to debug your JCL.  It is *way* beyond the scope of an answer on this site to explain the syntax of JCL.  [IBM's JCL Reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=mvs-zos-jcl-reference) will give you syntax.

The thing to do is look up the error message you received.  IBM error messages start with a code such as IEF452I followed by a message.  Often these messages will tell you exactly what went wrong, but not *why*, which can be frustrating.  In this example, the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=messages-ief452i) tells you there was an error, but not what the error is.  That's likely in *another* message.

Again, one point of the Master The Mainframe contest is to give you practice in looking these things up so you can solve problems on your own.